# Python linter does not work in VSCode since update causing settings deprecation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am having an issue with pylint in VSCode (and any python linter actually). Some update caused the settings I had in settings.json to deprecate and now linting won't work in my environment while it was working perfectly fine a few months ago. I have spent 2 days trying to fix this issue and I don't have any more time to spare for this at work. Please help. Linting works perfectly for C++ for some reason, but not for Python.

I have tried both Pylint and flake8, none seem to work for me. Pylint used to work perfectly fine and that's what I had been using all this time.

Comment: related: [Why does the VS Code Python extension (circa v2018.19) no longer provide support for several Python tools like linters and formatters?](/q/77283648/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can install different Linter extensions separately to obtain Linting function.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_choose-a-linter